# Efficient transcoding of Jackson parsed JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using Jackson streaming API to deserialise a quite large JSON (on the order of megabytes) into POJO. It's working fine, but I'd like to optimize it (both memory and processing wise, code runs on Android).

The main problem I'd like to optimize away is converting a large number of strings from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1. Currently I use:

```
String result = new String(parser.getText().getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
```

As I understand it, parser originally copies token content into String (getText()), then creates a byte array from it (getBytes()), which is then used to create a final String in desired encoding. Way too much allocations and copying.

Ideal solution would be if getText() would accept the encoding parameter and just give me the final string, but that's not the case.

Any other ideas, or flaws in my thinking?

Comment: Confused here:  JSON is UTF-whatever by definition.  A Java String is UTF16 characters.  Where did ISO-8859-1 come from??

Comment: Why would you encode a String to ISO-8859-1, then decode it as the default charset? The only time I've seen code even halfway like this is to reinterpret misencoded strings.

Comment: It is a case of strangely encoded strings, but those are coming via HTTP requests from a server I have no control over and cannot simply change its behavior. Above code is the way to force it to produce correctly encoded strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
parser.getBinaryValue() (present on version 2.4 of Jackson)
```

or you can implement an ObjectCodec (with a method readValue(...) that knows converting bytes to String in ISO8859-1) and set it using parser.setCodec().

If you have control over the json generation, avoid using a charset different than UTF-8.

Comment: I tried getBinaryValue, but it assumes the content is base64 encoded and tries to decode it, which doesn't help in this case.